# Solidity- calling function of a deployed contact from within another function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to call a function of an already deployed contract from within another contract.

```
import "./TutorialToken.sol";
contract Sellers
{ 
  TutorialToken _tt;

  constructor(address _f) public
  {
      _tt = TutorialToken(_f);
  }

  _tt.f();
}
```

However when I try and truffle migrate I get an error "Sellers" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!

I am confused on how I call the function of an already deployed contract from within another contract.

EDIT

initial deployment

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require('./Migrations.sol')

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations)
}
```

deploying contracts

```
const TutorialToken = artifacts.require('./TutorialToken.sol')
const Sellers = artifacts.require('./Sellers.sol')

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TutorialToken),
  deployer.deploy(Sellers)
}
```

Migrations.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Migrations {
address public owner;
uint public last_completed_migration;

modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
}

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
}

function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
}
```

}

Comment: What is this incomplete piece of code? Please provide a minimal working example, including both contracts and the function from which `_tt.f()` is invoked. Your code here will not compile!

Comment: Also, in order to answer your question, what we would really need to see is your Truffle migration script, which is not even present here.

Comment: I am aware this won't compile, I have taken code out in order to simplify the question. It doesn't matter what the contract TutorialToken is or what the function it is calling is, my question is about how in general one calls a method from a contract that has been already deployed, rather than making a new instance of the contract. I have updated my question to show my initial migration script and the contract deployments.

Comment: You are trying to deploy `Sellers` without passing constructor arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to deploy the `Sellers` without passing constructor arguments.

You also have a suspicious comma in that piece of code up there.

Change this:

```
deployer.deploy(TutorialToken), // what's this comma for?
deployer.deploy(Sellers)
```

To this:

```
deployer.deploy(TutorialToken).then(function() {
  return deployer.deploy(Sellers, TutorialToken.address);
});
```

See [Truffle documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer) for more details.